# Confused with UiBinder code

Tags: gwt

I get this code from tutorialspoint.com/gwt as I was learning UiBinder.
Actually I am confused about what does the second line actually does? Why are we using interface name as a ".class" argument in create() function.And what the parameters "widget" and "login" resembles in UiBinder. 
The code is:

```
 public class Login extends Composite 
{
      private static LoginUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(LoginUiBinder.class);
       @UiTemplate("Login.ui.xml")
      interface LoginUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Login> 
     {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every widget that is declared in a template is created by a call to **GWT.create()**.

The **UiBinder** interface declares two parameter types:

> U is the type of root element declared in the ui.xml file, returned by the createAndBindUi call
>
> O is the owner type whose @UiFields are to be filled in.

(In your example `U` is Widget and `O` is Login.)

Refer this [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html)